# Powershell - find a string in a text file and split the file at the start of the row of the text

Tags: powershell, text, split, line

I have a very large text file of documents that need to be split up every time it sees "Page: 1 of".  But I need it to split at the start of the row where it finds the text.

Example data:

[image]

I have the code below and it will split it every time it sees "Page: 1 of", however, it splits it at the match and not at the beginning of the line of the match.  So it removes the numbers at the start of the line which I need to keep and also it no longer lines up to the right properly.

```
(Get-Content -Raw TEST.TXT) -split '(?=Page:  1 of)' | Set-Content -LiteralPath { 'E:\test\TEST_OUT{0}.txt' -f $script:index++ }
```

It comes out like this.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Turn on the *multi-line* regex option with inline option `(?m)` so as to make `^` and `$` match the start and end of *each line*.
- Adapt the look-ahead assertion to look at the start of each line (`^`), followed by a non-empty number (`+`) of non-newline characters (`.`) before substring `Page:  1 of`, with the substring starting at a word boundary (`\b`).

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw TEST.TXT) -split '(?m)(?=^.+\bPage:  1 of)' |
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { 'E:\test\TEST_OUT{0}.txt' -f $script:index++ }
```

Note: If needed, you could further constrain the look-ahead assertion so as require that the line starts with a sequence of digits (`\d+`), for instance.